# Is it possible to read hdfs files from within executor

Tags: apache-spark

I have a simple spark application to illustate my question, I would like to read the hdfs files within `mapPartitions` operator,using `SparkContext.textFile`, so that, I could read the files in every partition and use that to work with `partitionIter`

It looks that I can't use SparkContext? Then, What could I do to achieve my purpose: hdfs files work with partitionIter.

```
object SparkTest2 {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkTest")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val rdd = sc.textFile("test1")
    rdd.mapPartitions {
      partitionIter => {
        //Read from HDFS for each partition
        //Is it possible to read hdfs files from within executor
        Seq("a").toIterator
      }
    }.collect()

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO: Usually using the standard way (read on driver and pass to executors using spark functions) is much easier operationally then doing things in a non-standard way. So in this case (with limited details) read the files on driver as dataframe and join with it.

That said have you tried using `--files` option for your `spark-submit` (or `pyspark`):

```
--files FILES     Comma-separated list of files to be placed in the working
                  directory of each executor. File paths of these files
                  in executors can be accessed via SparkFiles.get(fileName).
```